# Do I need a menu item with alias for all sef urls in Joomla?

Tags: url, joomla, joomla-sef-urls, sef, joomla1.7

I'm new to Joomla so my comprehension of how it all works is a bit incomplete. I'd just like to know whether or not I need to add new menu items with an alias for all short urls used in the application (e.g. http://mysite/shorturl). What bothers me is that:

1. Why would I need to make a menu item for an alias if I don't use the item in a menu (why such a relationship between urls and menus).
2. If I had 50 articles using short urls (aliases), would I have to make a menu item for every single short url? There's some dependencies I don't like about that.

I thought it made sense to set the alias on an article level.

I read something about having to purchase an extension sh404-something for this - really?

If someone could help me out it would be much appriciated.

Thanks and regards,
Kjetil

Comment: I'm really confused by your question. So SEF URL's aren't enough? You want to have further short urls? In Joomla, menu-items can be used to display articles, all the articles in a category (blog style) (these are the 2 most useful ones) and do a bunch of different sort of listing. A menu item is not more than creating a link to a page. All articles and menu items must have aliases and you're right that these make up part of the SEF url.

Comment: btw, my personal website is on Joomla, I'd love to help but I just have a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: I'm just having a hard time grasping the concept of menu item = url. Normally if I had a category containing articles I'd expect an option where I could generate a menu with all the articles (if I had to code it myself then no problem), in Joomla it seems I have to make the menu manually AND attach articles to the menu. So everytime I make a new article I have to add a new menu item. Is this correct?

Comment: Note: with disabled SEF urls then generating the menu i mentioned earlier would probably be possible, but when SEF urls are enabled - even if I use the matching article alias it won't work (of course not) because you need a menu item to "create" a short url

Comment: No, menu items should represent categories unless you want the equal of a static page (on my website that would be "About me", "Contact me". Its a pain, you have to create a category, put all your articles in a category, then create a menu item that has a blog layout for that category. Basically you have to jump around in 3 places to get things done. Then when you add something new to the category, it will automatically appear as the first item under the menu item assigned to that category examples from my site would be Blog, Development Work, Health and Fitness)

Comment: Each article has its own unique url, even it's own unique SEF url. The only reason for have the menu item there is because there has to be a way to locally group and link things. Try this, create a category called "Things Starting with A" then create 3 articles and put them in that category. Create a menu item with a blog layout assigned to the category "Things Starting with A". When you click the menu item you should see your 3 articles, when you click their title you should see them on a single page with their own URL.

Comment: Oh right. I think I'm starting to get an idea now. Thanks for your help : )

Comment: @kjetilh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2627/discussion-between-ali-and-kjetilh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each article has its own unique url, even it's own unique SEF url. The only reason for have the menu item there is because there has to be a way to locally group and link things. Try this, create a category called "Things Starting with A" then create 3 articles and put them in that category. Create a menu item with a blog layout assigned to the category "Things Starting with A". When you click the menu item you should see your 3 articles, when you click their title you should see them on a single page with their own URL.